# PHP function always returns same value

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress post 2 post plugin to connect actors to films. Trying to display actor info including his films(ID's).

Each time function runs, the $value variable is always different number, but somehow function result always is the same.

**$result** always creates empty array, when function runs.
**$variable** is different each time, that means **$post_val** is also different each time function runs, same for **$list** and **$post**.

I have no idea what's is wrong with my code then.

```
function get_connected_values($value) {
    $post_val = get_post($value);
    $related = p2p_type( 'actors_to_films' )->get_connected($post_val);
    $list = $related->posts;
    $result = [];
    foreach ($list as $post) {
        array_push($result, $post->ID);
    }   
    if (empty($result)) {
        return '';
    } else {
        $res = implode(",", $result);
        return $res; //always returns same, smt like 1111,1113,1114
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `p2p_type( 'actors_to_films' )->get_connected()` do?

Comment: Gets all related posts to current post($value) as objects.

Comment: Can you post the code for that function, because it looks like that's the actual function always returning the same result, at least in this context.

Comment: If I just print $post->ID in loop, it prints me all connected posts.

Comment: But it's the same everytime? If so, then that's why the end result is always the same. If not, please rephrase your question, I'm having difficulty understanding.

Comment: will you show me the $list array?